# python program getting stuck in between

Tags: python, multithreading, command-prompt, stock, hung

I am running a multi threaded python program in command-prompt which continuously fetches stocks data from data source.
However sometimes the program gets hung anywhere in code.
When I press some key on keyboard it resumes again.

```
import threading
import time

def check_program_status():
    while True:
        print("Program is running...")
        time.sleep(300)


def fetch_stocks_data():
    pass

status_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_program_status)
status_thread.daemon = True  
status_thread.start()


while True:
    try:
        fetch_stocks_data()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

To counter this problem I am printing few lines after 5 minute interval to see if program is running or not.
But its not possible for me to monitor the program all the time.
Is there any other solution to this.